# SELECT Duplicate/Repeating values with count N without COUNT or GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table of person id's(1-8) and person roles(1-4) as such:

```
CREATE TABLE personRole (
PersonId int NOT NULL,
RoleId int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO personRole
VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 1),
(2, 3),
(3, 3),
(4, 3),
(1, 4),
(5, 2),
(6, 1),
(7, 1),
(7, 4),
(8, 1),
(8, 2),
(8, 4)
;
```

My goal is to select the person id's who have 3 or more roles and the roles are specifically 1, 2, and 4. Here is my first solution:

```
SELECT PersonId FROM personRole
WHERE RoleID in (1,2,4)
GROUP BY PersonId
HAVING count(*) >= 3
```

But then I was told to do it without GROUP BY because it is slow so I came up with this solution:

```
SELECT distinct PersonId
FROM 
(
  SELECT PersonId, count(*) over(partition by PersonId) AS pcount
  FROM (SELECT * FROM personRole WHERE RoleID in (1,2,4)) AS A
) AS S
WHERE pcount >= 3
```

I've included these to give an example of what I am trying to achieve.
But now I have been told to attempt it without count. I am currently able to find all rows that have duplicate/repeating person id's with such:

```
 SELECT personId
 FROM personRole AS a
 WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   personRole AS a2
   WHERE  a2.PersonId = a.PersonId
   AND    a2.RoleID <> a.RoleID
 );
```

But I am stuck trying to find out how to only select them if they repeat 3 or more times. If I am able then I suspect I can just INTERSECT it with:

```
SELECT PersonId FROM personRole
WHERE RoleID in (1,2,4)
```

To get my full solution. Am I solving this correctly so far or am I going in the wrong direction?

Comment: It can't be greater than 3 can it? I think you should revisit your original query and explore why it's slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "without count", does the dictator mean no aggregate functions? You could always sum(1) instead of count(*).

Otherwise, try a self join.

```
select a.PersonId, 
   a.RoleId, 
   b.RoleId, 
   c.RoleId,
   d.RoleId
from personRole a
    left join personRole b
    on a.PersonId = b.PersonId
    and a.RoleId <> b.RoleId
left join personRole c
    on a.PersonId = c.PersonId
    and a.RoleId <> c.RoleId
    and b.RoleId <> c.RoleId
left join personRole d
    on a.PersonId = d.PersonId
    and a.RoleId <> d.RoleId
    and b.RoleId <> d.RoleId
    and c.RoleId <> d.RoleId
order by a.PersonId, a.RoleId
;

+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| PersonId | RoleId | RoleId | RoleId | RoleId |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|        1 |      1 |      4 |      2 |   NULL |
|        1 |      1 |      2 |      4 |   NULL |
|        1 |      2 |      4 |      1 |   NULL |
|        1 |      2 |      1 |      4 |   NULL |
|        1 |      4 |      2 |      1 |   NULL |
|        1 |      4 |      1 |      2 |   NULL |
|        2 |      1 |      3 |   NULL |   NULL |
|        2 |      3 |      1 |   NULL |   NULL |
|        3 |      3 |   NULL |   NULL |   NULL |
|        4 |      3 |   NULL |   NULL |   NULL |
|        5 |      2 |   NULL |   NULL |   NULL |
|        6 |      1 |   NULL |   NULL |   NULL |
|        7 |      1 |      4 |   NULL |   NULL |
|        7 |      4 |      1 |   NULL |   NULL |
|        8 |      1 |      2 |      4 |   NULL |
|        8 |      1 |      4 |      2 |   NULL |
|        8 |      2 |      1 |      4 |   NULL |
|        8 |      2 |      4 |      1 |   NULL |
|        8 |      4 |      2 |      1 |   NULL |
|        8 |      4 |      1 |      2 |   NULL |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Restrict that with a where clause that looks for values in c.RoleId - and use your magic numbers to cull the cartesian product like so:

```
select a.PersonId, 
       a.RoleId, 
       b.RoleId, 
       c.RoleId
from personRole a
left join personRole b
    on a.PersonId = b.PersonId
left join personRole c
    on a.PersonId = c.PersonId
where 
    b.RoleId <> a.RoleId
    and b.RoleId <> c.RoleId
    and c.RoleId <> a.RoleId
    and c.RoleId <> b.RoleId
    and a.RoleId = 1
    and b.RoleId = 2
    and c.RoleId = 4
order by a.PersonId, a.RoleId
;

+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| PersonId | RoleId | RoleId | RoleId |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|        1 |      1 |      2 |      4 |
|        8 |      1 |      2 |      4 |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want it even more compact, and you're only searching for this one case, you can do away with the left joins and value comparisons all together

```
mysql> select a.PersonId, 
    ->        a.RoleId, 
    ->        b.RoleId, 
    ->        c.RoleId
    -> from personRole a,
    ->      personRole b,
    ->      personRole c
    -> where 
    ->     a.PersonId = b.PersonId
    ->     and a.PersonId = c.PersonId
    ->     and a.RoleId = 1
    ->     and b.RoleId = 2
    ->     and c.RoleId = 4
    -> order by a.PersonId, a.RoleId
    -> ;
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| PersonId | RoleId | RoleId | RoleId |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|        1 |      1 |      2 |      4 |
|        8 |      1 |      2 |      4 |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is a great solution! Thank you! Thanks for giving the tip about sum as well, I'll keep that in my pocket. It is unknown if I was restricted from all aggregates, but you gave tips for both.

Comment: could you explain a bit?... up for you

Comment: How does this solve the `only select them if they repeat 3 or more times` and `the roles are specifically 1, 2, and 4` parts of the question?

Comment: @DanielH I'm happy to explain, is there any part you're specifically curious about?

Comment: @JenR If c.RoleID is not null, then there are values in a.RoleId and b.RoleId that differ from c.RoleId, bringing the total number of RoleIds for that PersonId to 3 or greater. A where clause to inspect the resultant RoleIds for the necessary set could be done 100 ways, my favorite of which is "where a.RoleId + b.RoleId + c.RoleId = 7" ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could do self-joins, though I don't know that it would be more efficient than your other solutions.  It would get rid of any aggregate functions since you seem to be restricted from using them.

```
select a.PersonId
from personRole a
    join personRole b on a.PersonId = b.PersonId
        and b.RoleId = 2
    join personRole c on a.PersonId = c.PersonId
        and c.RoleId = 4
where a.RoleId = 1
```